# Get access to my derived class members

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have several classes that inhabit from this class:

```
 public abstract class Class1
{
    private string _protocol;
    private static List<Plus> _class1Objects;

    public string Protocol
    {
        get { return _protocol; }
        set { _protocol = value; }
    }

    public static List<Plus> Class1Objects
    {
        get { return _class1Objects; }
        set { _class1Objects = value; }
    }
}
```

And the derive class:

```
public class Class2 : Plus
{
    public bool name;
    public int id;

}

public Webmail(string name, int id)
{
    if (Class1Objects == null)
        Class1Objects = new List<class1>();

    .....

    Class1Objects.Add(this);
}
```

And after my list is full of `Class1Objects`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Class1.Class1Objects.Count; i++)
{
    if (Class1.Class1Objects[i].GetType() == typeof(Class2))
    }   
         (Class2)Class1.Class1Objects[i]. 
    }
}
```

Here after `(Class2)Class1.Class1Objects[i].` i cannot see my `Class2` memners

Comment: This really sounds like a broken abstraction.  If every instance in `Class1Objects` is required to be of type `Class2` then it should be a collection of type `Class2`.  Why abstract it if you're not using the abstraction?

Comment: @David Not every instance is required to be type Class2. Hence the type check in the loop.

Comment: @itsme86: Fair point.  Still, it's a code smell and a violation of Liskov Substitution.

Comment: @David i have several classes that inherit from Class1, this is only example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one additional paranthese:

```
((Class2)Class1.Class1Objects[i]).
```

At the moment it is read as the following:

```
(Class2)(Class1.Class1Objects[i].) //<= at the '.' it is still a class1
```

BUT as David said in his comment: If all are of type `Class2` it should be a collection of that type and if not you should check the type, altogether with `foreach`:

```
foreach(var item in Class1.Class1Objects)
{
    if(item is Class2)
        ((Class2)Class1.Class1Objects[i]).
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```
((Class2)Class1.Class1Objects[i]).name;
```

Because in your case, when you type something like this:

```
(Class2)Class1.Class1Objects[i].name;
```

You try to access the member `name` of `Class1.Class1Objects[i]`, and only after that you try to cast it to `Class2`.

Also, the whole loop would be much simpler if you used foreach:

```
using System.Linq;

foreach(Class2 c in Class1.Class1Objects.OfType<Class2>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.name); // or whatever you need to do with it
}
```

Comment: `foreach(Class2 c in Class1.Class1Objects)` gives you an `InvalidCastException` if one item is NOT `Class2`...

Comment: Forgot the OfType statement

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner to use `as`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Class1.Class1Objects.Count; i++)
{
    var c2 = Class1.Class1Objects[i] as Class2;
    if (c2!=null)
    }   
         c2.<whatever was meant to come after the .>
    }
}
```

You might also want to consider switching to `foreach` unless there's a specific reason you want to manually extract each element from the `List`, e.g. if you're actually storing new values back into the list.